# How to fire masonry reload twice?

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, reload, jquery-masonry

I'm still quite new to jQuery so bear with me...
I'm using the masonry plugin, here's my code—

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".pics-hidden").hide();

      $('.pics').click(function() {
            $('#div'+$(this).attr('rarget')).addClass('pics').removeClass('#div'+$(this).attr('rarget')).delay(600).fadeIn(400);
            $('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
      });

      $('.close').click(function() {
            $('#div'+$(this).attr('larget')).addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#div'+$(this).attr('larget')).delay(600).fadeOut(400);
            $('#projectimages').masonry('reload');
            return false;
      });
});
```

Clicking on .pics will show a hidden div by changing the class and reload the masonry plugin, but when you try to close these divs using the close button (.close) the divs successfully close but the masonry doesn't reload this time and leaves a blank space.
Here's the template I'm working on — [www.nealfletcher.co.uk/testingtesting](http://www.nealfletcher.co.uk/testingtesting) 
So I'm wondering if it's possible to fire the .masonry('reload') twice, or any other solution that would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not really looked into what masonry actually does,
but you may want to move `$('#projectimages').masonry('reload');`

before

```
return false;
```

in `$('.close').click(function() {...});` as nothing is executed after the return statement.

**EDIT :** (removed 'pics' class on close)

```
$('.close').click(function() {
      $('#div'+$(this).attr('larget')).removeClass('pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#div'+$(this).attr('larget')).delay(600).fadeOut(400);
      $('#projectimages').masonry('reload'); 
      return false;      
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I've tried a few variations with 'return false;' and moving it to the bottom still doesn't work.

Comment: You may have to remove the 'pics' class on close. Something like $('#div'+$(this).attr('larget')).removeClass('pics').addClass('.pics-hidden').removeClass('#div'+$(this).attr('larget')).delay(600).fadeOut(400);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and add

```
$(".pics-hidden").hide();
```

in the close button and before the masonry reload? I've a similar problem and I solved it completely different. I hope it helps. But it seems to work now. I can't see a gap?